# Underlined When Writing - Flutter - Textfield

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Whenever I write the word is underlined. As soon as I write a new word, it will no longer be underlined, but what I am currently writing. Can I somehow issue that nothing is underlined when writing? I didn't find anything in the forum either.

[image: UNDERLINE]

```
child: TextField(
                  autocorrect: false,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 22.0,
                  ),
                  cursorColor: Colors.black,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Search',
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.search,
                      color: Color(0xFFe1F5FE),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: The behaviour you described seems to be due to your settings on your device, to do spell checking. I can see you have enabled the auto-suggestion bar on top of the keyboard as well.

Comment: okay, sure. I don't have to issue it through the app.

Comment: Try the `autocorrect` property of the `Textfield` and set it to `false` @Florian

Answer (score 0):

did you try it with `focusedBorder`?

```
TextField(
      decoration: new InputDecoration(
          border: InputBorder.none,
          focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, bottom: 11, top: 11, right: 15),
          hintText: 'what you want'
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: From what I understand from the documentation, `focusedBorder` applies a border to the whole field when it is focused and doesn't have any errors. The O.P. described the behaviour as having the current typed word underlined, but will stop being underlined after writting a new word.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code inside TextField

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
```

Example:

```
TextField(
                 keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  autocorrect: false,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 22.0,
                  ),
                  cursorColor: Colors.black,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Search',
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.search,
                      color: Color(0xFFe1F5FE),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```